# Installing MySql 5.5 on Debian with the deb package

Tags: debian, dpkg, mysql5.5

I'm setting up a debian server as a development server. apt-get gave me everything I need to install, except for mysql 5.5 as this version is still in the experimental branch.

So what I tried to do is download the .deb package from the mysql website, and execute :

```
dpkg -D1 -i mysql-5.5.19-debian6.0-x86_64.deb
```

The command shows this :

```
Selecting previously deselected package mysql.
(Reading database ... 38342 files and directories currently installed)
Unpacking mysql (from mysql-5.5.19-debian6.0-x86_64.deb) ...
D000001: process_archive oldversionstatus=not installed
D000001: process_archive updating info directory
Setting up mysql (5.5.19) ...
D000001: deferred_configure updating conffiles
```

... and exits. But I can't find anything installed. No executables, no configuration files.

What am I missing ? How do I install mysql 5.5 on Debian ?

Thanks !

Comment: What shows up if you run: `dpkg -L mysql`

Comment: It show me a whole bunch of files in the /opt/mysql folder. Are these the installed files ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mysql package installed into /opt/mysql.

You'll need to run the programs from there. You probably want to add the mysql bin directory to your path.

Alternatively, does testing or unstable have mysql 5.5?

Comment: Thanks. Only experimental does have 5.5 so far. To wrap up, the .deb package actually just puts the server files in a folder, but nothing more. I had to follow all the installation steps detailed in the MySql documentation (section 2) and I had the server working without too much hassle.